# Send HTML Form using SMTP

Tags: php, html, email

We have a HTML form that collect data and submit to a PHP page that send the form data to our email.
The issue is that we are using AWS server and AWS has a block on port 25 which the result the email not sending properly.
Our situation now when we send the form to a regular Gmail account the email goes to spam, however when we send it to a Gsuite account the email never received not even as a spam email.
We are thinking of just using SMTP to send our email without going to spam or not receiving it.

Our HTML Code:

```
<form name='form1' action="/wp-includes/phpmailer2/sendMail.php" >
        
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" >
          
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$webmaster_email = "user@example.com";

$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "https://rentersshield.org/success/";

$msg = "First Name: " . $first_name . "\r\n" .

function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (!isset($_REQUEST['first_name'])) {
    header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
} elseif (empty($first_name) ) {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
} elseif ( isInjected($first_name)  || isInjected($comments) ) {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
} else {

    mail( "$webmaster_email", "New Form Submission", $msg );
    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>

$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'] ;
```

Please let us know if there is something to be done to send it to our Gsuite email account without going into spam

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Yes, maybe send it via the GSuite SMTP instead of your local mailserver. Use PHPMailer in PHP to make that easier.

Comment: `$msg = "First Name: " . $first_name . "\r\n" .` TYPO, that dog wont hunt

Comment: `$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'] ;` Outside PHP tags, another dog that wont hunt?

Comment: How to use SMTP  instead of local mailserver, that was our question. When we follow the examples in https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, the code doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" tells us nothing about your exact problem. Show the phpmailer code, show relevant data, give us a [mre] of the issue, if you want help with it. PHPMailer _is_ the way to use SMTP in PHP, so if you're having a specific issue we might be able to help if you tell us what it is. Also note that PHPMailer has a verbose debugging mode you can enable, which should give you clues about the nature of the problem, if you aren't getting PHP errors directly. Also make sure you've got PHP error reporting / logging switched on so you can see any php-related errors clearly too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only managed to fix our issue by sending it via SMTP but we have to install PHPmailer first on cPanel using the following command
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer

Instructions: https://muftsabazaar.com/blog/post/how-to-install-the-phpmailer-in-cpanel
Then we updated our PHP code as below

```
<?php
use phpmailer\phpmailer\PHPMailer;
use phpmailer\phpmailer\Exception;
 
require '/home/rentersshield/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/rentersshield/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home/rentersshield/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

 
// Instantiation and passing [ICODE]true[/ICODE] enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

 try {

    //Server settings

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'example@domain.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'emailpass';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, [ICODE]ssl[/ICODE] also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

 
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('example@domain.com', 'New Form submission on Rentersshield Website');
    $mail->addAddress('example@domain.com', 'JohnUser');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('example@domain.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('example@domain.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('example@domain.com');
    $mail->addBCC('example@domain.com');
 
$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "https://rentersshield.org/success/";    
 
    // Content
    $first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'] ;
    
   
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 
    "First Name: " . $first_name . "\r\n" ;
 
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    
     $mail->send();
    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at PHPMailer or any SMTP class where you have more control over authentication and server responses. The php function mail is too basic.

PHPMailer is a classic, and it works quite well on all my applications. Here is a link if you might want to take a look:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

The documentaton is quite complete so you would be able to implement it without no problems.

Comment: We tried to do that and it give us the below error" This page isn’t working" link: https://rentersshield.org/mailer.php

Comment: I went to see it and it seems to be working now.